# como enviar datos de formulario usando vuejs y js a php?

Tags: php, javascript, vue.js

quiero enviar los datos del formulario a php usando vuejs y js, se que para enviarlo mediante post con vuejs hay que usar axios, pero en ninguna parte sale claramente como hacerlo.

formulario:

```
<div id="contenedor">
              <h1>Welcome admin</h1>
              <form action="index.php?url=login">
                <label>User:</label>
                <input type="text" name="user" v-model = "user">
                <label>Pass:</label>
                <input type="text" name="pass" v-model = "pass">
                <button @click="login">Login</button>
               </form>
 </div>
```

js:

```
contenedor  = new Vue ({
    el: '#contenedor',
    data: {
        user: '',
        pass: '',
    },
    methods: {
        login: function() {
        }
    }
})
```

en el metodo login es donde deberia poner

```
axios.post("index.php?url=login", {'user':this.user, 'pass':this.pass}).then(response)
```

pero no sale en ninguna parte la sintaxis y tampoco se como obtener esos datos en el archivo login

login:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

return $data->user;?>
```

es la unica duda que tengo, como enviar esos datos al archivo php, estos verlos, hacer lo que hay que hacer con ellos, retornarlos y luego mostrarlos

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer la petición, es correcto lo que comentas:

```
login: function() {
    axios.post("index.php?url=login", {user:this.user, pass:this.pass})
    .then(response => {
        if (response)
            // Tus validaciones
    })
}
```

Luego, para recuperar esos datos prueba a acceder al elemento como array y no como objeto:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo $data['user'];
?>
```

De todas formas, asegúrate que estás consiguiendo llamar correctamente a tu backend php.